# Between R squart

Tags: stata, covariance, panel-data

i'm useing the between R^2 to validate the predictive power of my FE model (output -xtreg) . I like to use it for a paper but cant find a source (paper or book) which descrips the logic of between R^2 (just for citation not understanding)

Someone knows a source?

im greatefull for every hint.

dave

Answer (score 0):

You can cite the Stata pdf/dead tree documentation for `xtreg, fe` like this:

> StataCorp. 2017. Stata Statistical Software: Release 15. College
>   Station, TX: StataCorp LLC

All the versions are available on-line. You can even link [to the very page with the formulas](https://www.stata.com/manuals/xtxtreg.pdf#page=27).